# Possible to build and OR gate out of only AND/NOT?

Tags: circuit-design, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

Is it possible to construct an `OR` gate from only a combination of a `NOT` and an `AND` gate? Or possible to build an `AND` gate out of only an `OR` gate and a `NOT` gate? In other words, can all gates be built from only two logic gates (inversion, and), or are three needed (inversion, and, or)?

Comment: This question can be answered by simply using the truth tables amd boolean equations to see the outputs and conclude if it's behaves like a or gate. So why are you asking us to do the work for you????

Comment: @Joey sure I've looked at the tables which gives all the gates by themselves: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-of-logic-gates/. But I'm more interested in the combinational logic.

Comment: You already asked a combinational logic question before. This shows you are not interested in learning but rather just want others to do the work for you. This is NOT right and you should refrain from the doing this in the future!

Comment: @Joey thanks for the feedback. Yes I enjoy doing the work and even posted an answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any combinatorial logic function can be implemented with just NAND gates.

And you can make a NAND gate from an AND and a NOT.

Therefore any combinatorial logic function can be implemented with AND and NOT gates.

OR is an example of a combinatorial logic function.

Therefore an OR gate can be implemented with AND and NOT gates.

> can all gates be built from only two logic gates (inversion, and), or are three needed (inversion, and, or)?

As mentioned above, all gates can be built from just one gate type.

In fact you can use either NAND or NOR gates to construct any combinatorial function.

In real-world implementations, an AND gate is very often implemented using a NAND and a NOT, and an OR is very often implemented using a NOR and a NOT.

Comment: thanks for this answer. Could you show the combination (or link to an example) that shows an example OR gate built out of only AND/ORs ?

Comment: @David542, that wasn't part of the question asked. And also, we prefer not to do your homework for you, rather to teach you enough to understand how to do your homework yourself.

Comment: got it, I've added a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can build this as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRifaB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is using de Morgan's:

```
    AND(NOT A, NOT B) = NOT(OR(A,B)) // NOR GATE
--> NOT(AND(NOT A, NOT B) = OR(A,B)  // INVERTED NOR GATE
```

Comment: Please don't give out homework answers without expecting the OP to do most of the work themselves. We don't want to turn this site into a homework solution service.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson hm? I am the OP.

Comment: It was confusing when you started as though talking to someone else: "Sure, **you** can..."